# Uploading Larger Files in php

Tags: php, file-upload

In my site I have to upload very large files.File size may be up to 200MB.
What approach should i follow to upload these files in less duration.Is there any concept of binary uploading in php?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Uploads *are* binary. It takes however long it takes over HTTP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
For complete reference.

Comment: You'd be better off using a dedicated file transfer protocol, like sftp, instead of http. At least with sftp you can generally resume aborted uploads, etc... and don't have to worry about PHP's rather ludicrously stupid internal design for file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading large files over HTTP is obviously not perfect, which was why FTP was designed.

However, given what you have got to work with, there are a few things you can do to help make the process smoother.

Make sure that you set the appropriate settings in PHP:

- `max_upload_size` to an appropriate size
- `set_time_limit(0);`, so that the script does not time out.

Other settings that require tweaking:

- `memory_limit`
- `post_max_size`
- `max_input_time`

Comment: There is no issue of Uploading of File as all the Settings are already been done.The issue is of speed.How can i speed up the entire process of Uploading such a large file?.

Comment: There is no way to speed up or affect the HTTP transfer, without installing any special addons to the client (browser).

Answer (score 0):

1.change the **max_upload_size** in php.ini for appropriate size.

2.Set your script timeout to never (set_time_limit(0); in your scripts… don’t do this in your php.ini)

check these links

http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/uploading-large-files-with-php/

http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/